# Can ElasticSearch work complex Bool Query? ex: (A and B) or (C and D)

Tags: elasticsearch

I know ES search have must, should and must not.
If I want A and B. I can use two condition in must. Or even A and B and C ..., I can put them total in must.
Edited:
But I don't know how to implement (A and B) or (C an D), dose ES can do?

Origin:
But I don't know how to implement (A and B) or C, dose ES can do?

Answer Test:

```
POST test/test
{
    "name": "I she"
}
```

The below will not search any article.

```
POST test/test/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
          "bool": {
              "should": [
                   {
                     "bool": {
                         "must": [{"match" : { "name" : "I" }}, {"match" : { "name" : "him" }}]
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "bool": {
                         "must": [{"match" : { "name" : "her" }}, {"match" : { "name" : "she" }}]
                     }
                 }
              ]
          }
      }
}
```

It will search the article

```
POST test/test/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [{"match" : { "name" : "I" }}, {"match" : { "name" : "him" }}]
                   }
               },
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": {"match" : { "name" : "her" }}
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put A and B in must clause and put C in Should clause

Comment: thank u, it works.    
But if more complex like (A and B) or (C and D)    
example:   
I want to search (I and he) or (she and her). The article has I and she.
If I put she and her in Should clause, this article will be searched.
I want this is not be searched.
Sorry, I change my question.

Comment: For that case you should write query like this - should(must(A, B), must(C,D))

Answer (score 2):

For complex boolean conditions you should combine must and should in one query. For example if condition is (A and B) or (C and D) your query should look like

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [A, B]
                   }
               },
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [C, D]
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
GET index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "field1.keyword": {
                  "value": "A"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "field2.keyword": {
                  "value": "B"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "field1.keyword": {
                  "value": "C"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "field2.keyword": {
                  "value": "D"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```